# Do recursive calls count into space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, stack, complexity-theory, space-complexity

When an algorithm doesn't use more than a constant amount of auxiliary memory but does have `O(log(N))` recursive calls (each one taking some extra space on the stack), is that algorithm's space complexity `O(1)` or `O(log(N))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the recursive algorithm is not exploiting tail recursion, then, yes, a straightforward implementation would be using O(log(N)) space. This is because the runtime must keep O(log(N)) stack frames, each of O(1) size, in memory at once.